# Change the status bar color using UISplitViewController in iOS7

Tags: ios7, uisplitviewcontroller, statusbar

I'm updating an app that uses UISplitViewController and my client wants the status bar to have the same color of the navigation bar. I know that in ios7, the status bar became part of the view and we can change the view background color and use this solution as a fake status bar but in ios7, the status bar is presented like in ios6 (black status bar) and I don't know where to look for to change the color.

Can anyone give me a light?